# Can't find why this datetime test fails, in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following function, which was made with the help of some people here:

```
module DateTimeFormatter =

    let mutable year   = -1
    let mutable month  = -1
    let mutable day    = -1
    let mutable hour   = -1
    let mutable minute = -1
    let mutable second = -1
    let dateTimeArray  = "xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx".ToCharArray()
    let timeArray      = "xx:xx:xx.xxx".ToCharArray()
    let zeroChar       = int '0'

    // format the datetime into a date and a time with milliseconds
    let format (dateTime: DateTime) =

        if dateTime.Year <> year then
            year <- dateTime.Year
            dateTimeArray.[0] <- char (zeroChar + year / 1000)
            dateTimeArray.[1] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 1000) / 100)
            dateTimeArray.[2] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 100) / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[3] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 10))

        if dateTime.Month <> month then
            month <- dateTime.Month
            dateTimeArray.[5] <- char (zeroChar + month / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[6] <- char (zeroChar + month % 10)

        if dateTime.Day <> day then
            day <- dateTime.Day
            dateTimeArray.[8] <- char (zeroChar + day / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[9] <- char (zeroChar + day % 10)

        if dateTime.Hour <> hour then
            hour <- dateTime.Hour
            dateTimeArray.[11] <- char (zeroChar + hour / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[12] <- char (zeroChar + hour % 10)

        if dateTime.Minute <> minute then
            minute <- dateTime.Minute
            dateTimeArray.[14] <- char (zeroChar + minute / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[15] <- char (zeroChar + minute % 10)

        if dateTime.Second <> second then
            second <- dateTime.Second
            dateTimeArray.[17] <- char (zeroChar + second / 10)
            dateTimeArray.[18] <- char (zeroChar + second % 10)

        let ms = dateTime.Millisecond
        dateTimeArray.[20] <- char (zeroChar + ms / 100)
        dateTimeArray.[21] <- char (zeroChar + (ms % 100) / 10)
        dateTimeArray.[22] <- char (zeroChar + ms % 10)

        new string(dateTimeArray)
```

The idea is to build date time + millisecond timestamp as fast as possible.

But sometimes, and not always, I get this output:

> 2021-06-01 xx:xx:53.648

And the failure is always on the hours / minutes, but sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't. and I don't see anything wrong with the tests when building the string, but it looks like hour and minutes fail even the first test since there is the placeholder 'x' in place.

It may be one of these super simple things that require another set of eyes to see it :)

Comment: Are you running it many times concurrently by any chance?

Comment: yes, it's used in a bunch of async / parallel calls; I guess it would be conceivable that one call has an equality test passing while another one just set the value and hasn't set the chars yet, but then the problem would happen once and then the chars would be set after that

Comment: @Thomas create formatter per thread. Otherwise you have unpredictable results even if you don't observe 'xx'. E.g. hour might be modified by thread which just started formatting and it will affect the thread that creates a new string at the same time.

Comment: wasn't there a compiler mechanism in C# to request that fields would be per thread? I wonder if there is a F# equivalent. I think there was some attribute for that

Comment: Well, if you're claiming that it happens intermittently, not just on the first couple passes, then I'm afraid we'll need a repro.

Comment: there are 2 failures I have seen: the 'x' remaining and the time just being wrong. I could maybe do a loop that creates strings and parses them to make sure they're correct and run that in parallel to try to trigger the issue

Comment: @FyodorSoikin here is the repro https://pastebin.com/QxLjkXJ3

Comment: I've a jupyter notebook too, but SO won't let me post a wetransfer link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the mutables and `dateTimeArray` in the module is being walked all over from different threads. This is not thread safe code.

I posted some comments that I've now deleted, because I didn't look at the code long enough to understand the intention. The intention is obviously to optimize, but it fails. Simplifying the function will actually improve performance. The extra logic and extra variables didn't help, any of them. This code below is still faster.

I somewhat doubt that thread local storage can help the original code to beat this code, because I don't think it's in that logic any performance benefit can be found. I think the benefit over `DateTime.ToString` is in what's left in this simplified code:

```
let dateTimeArray = "xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx".ToCharArray()
let [<Literal>] zeroChar = 48 // '0'

let format (dateTime: DateTime) =

    let dateTimeArray = Array.copy dateTimeArray

    dateTimeArray.[0] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Year / 1000)
    dateTimeArray.[1] <- char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 1000) / 100)
    dateTimeArray.[2] <- char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 100) / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[3] <- char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 10))

    dateTimeArray.[5] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Month / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[6] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Month % 10)

    dateTimeArray.[8] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Day / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[9] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Day % 10)

    dateTimeArray.[11] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Hour / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[12] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Hour % 10)

    dateTimeArray.[14] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Minute / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[15] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Minute % 10)

    dateTimeArray.[17] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Second / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[18] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Second % 10)

    dateTimeArray.[20] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Millisecond / 100)
    dateTimeArray.[21] <- char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Millisecond % 100) / 10)
    dateTimeArray.[22] <- char (zeroChar + dateTime.Millisecond % 10)

    new string(dateTimeArray)
```

Reading properties of `dateTime` multiple times does not slow down the function. Reading a property once, e.g. reading `dateTime.Year` once into a local value and then use it in four places, will actually make the function slower.

Looks like this will shave off some more time, and the outer `dateTimeArray` isn't needed any more:

```
let dateTimeArray: char[] =
    [|
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Year / 1000)
        char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 1000) / 100)
        char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 100) / 10)
        char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Year % 10))
        '-'
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Month / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Month % 10)
        '-'
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Day / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Day % 10)
        ' '
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Hour / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Hour % 10)
        ':'
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Minute / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Minute % 10)
        ':'
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Second / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Second % 10)
        '.'
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Millisecond / 100)
        char (zeroChar + (dateTime.Millisecond % 100) / 10)
        char (zeroChar + dateTime.Millisecond % 10)
    |]
```

And I have one more version. The use of `Math.DivRem` seems to shave off slightly more, but the lookup into array `digits` adds time, though it brings some elegance.

```
let format (dateTime: DateTime) =
    let monthHigh, monthLow = Math.DivRem (dateTime.Month, 10)
    let dayHigh, dayLow = Math.DivRem (dateTime.Day, 10)
    let hourHigh, hourLow = Math.DivRem (dateTime.Hour, 10)
    let minuteHigh, minuteLow = Math.DivRem (dateTime.Minute, 10)
    let secondHigh, secondLow = Math.DivRem (dateTime.Second, 10)
    let digit = [| '0'; '1'; '2'; '3'; '4'; '5'; '6'; '7'; '8'; '9' |]
    [|
        digit.[dateTime.Year / 1000]
        digit.[(dateTime.Year % 1000) / 100]
        digit.[(dateTime.Year % 100) / 10]
        digit.[dateTime.Year % 10]
        '-'
        digit.[monthHigh]
        digit.[monthLow]
        '-'
        digit.[dayHigh]
        digit.[dayLow]
        ' '
        digit.[hourHigh]
        digit.[hourLow]
        ':'
        digit.[minuteHigh]
        digit.[minuteLow]
        ':'
        digit.[secondHigh]
        digit.[secondLow]
        '.'
        digit.[dateTime.Millisecond / 100]
        digit.[(dateTime.Millisecond % 100) / 10]
        digit.[dateTime.Millisecond % 10]
    |] |> (fun a -> new String(a))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking closely into this. The code was originally built to timestamp a lot of data coming from a stream; while it was clearly not thread safe, I still don't understand the issue where the 'x' characters were printed multiple times. I could understand one time where one call sets the variable on the test while another code passes the test before the x is overwritten, but I don't understand how it could happen several times.

Comment: One point I don't understand is this:  "Reading a property once, [...] into a local value and then use it in four places, will actually make the function slower." I have no clue how the dotnet compiler works, but, coming originally from the  ASM/C world, I can't understand how that would be possible since you'd load up the value in a register and use it multiple time from there, especially since the use of that value is very local and the code involved doesn't juggle between a lot of values. How can it be slower?

Comment: I don't know why it's slower, but a guess might be that more instructions than needed are generated, and not optimized away. And perhaps the compiler can optimize several accesses to these properties.

Comment: When mutable data is accessed unsafely from several threads, all rules go out the window. There's no point trying to make sense of what you see. You get these really weird magical effects. Modifications not taking effect is just a small part of the chaos that ensues. It has to do with each thread holding values in registers temporarily, and not expecting other threads to tamper with the same memory, and this is only part of the complexity. That 'x' could be in the memory, or in some thread's cache or register or something, while another thread has actually updated the memory.

Comment: Slightly off topic: I have sometimes used a bool to signal something from one thread to another. This doesn't work reliably right out of the box, because of these caching effects. You can actually get fooled, and see trouble only after you compile for release, or even sporadically only after deploying. But my point is; there are ways around it - but I don't have a good overview of them. Last time I did something like that, I believe I used a .NET call to somehow mark the bool as volatile. F# has a volatile keyword, but not sure if that can do the trick - possibly reserved for future use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692780/c-sharp-volatile-variable-memory-fences-vs-caching