# acquire memory barrier on stores

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Acquire memory barriers on load and release memory barrier on stores are used for synchronization across threads.

Is there a use case for the opposite, i.e. an acquire memory barrier on a store and consequently a release memory barrier on a load?

Comment: What do you mean by "barrier **on** stores"?  `atomic_thread_fence` (a barrier/fence) is separate from a load or store *operation* like `foo.store(1, std::memory_order_release)`.  If you mean using acquire as a memory *order* for a store operation like `.store(1, acquire)`, that's undefined behaviour: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store.  GCC happens to compile it like `seq_cst`, clang happens to compile it like `relaxed`: https://godbolt.org/z/bfWYxcK4M

Comment: Even for "weird" cases [like a SeqLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611003/implementing-64-bit-atomic-counter-with-32-bit-atomics), you want an extra acquire barrier in the reader for load-load ordering, and an extra release barrier in the writer for store-store ordering.  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) /

Comment: @PeterCordes here's a link that mentions about the use case for acquire memory barriers for store (and also the fact that it's UB). That said I'd like to understand that use case better or if there are other example uses.  https://youtu.be/R0V4xJ9HZpA?t=3822

Comment: Why didn't you quote the video in the question in the first place, and mention the Ticket Lock use-case it suggests?  At least you can do that now to save future readers the trouble of figuring out how to explain to you something you already know.

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock doesn't make it obvious why you'd want an acquire store.  It looks like the store at the end can be a plain store with release semantics with the version of the algorithm presented on wikipedia, since the thread that owns the lock knows what ticket number they had.  No atomic RMW needed.  But more importantly, no acquiring needed.  So Fedor must be talking about a more complicated version of the algorithm.)

Comment: I may setup another question on implementation of ticket lock. I still don't see how a acquire store barrier is needed in that case.

Comment: Also, when you edit this question, note that the `std::memory_order` parameter is a *memory order*, not a "memory barrier".  A compiler might end up implementing it with barriers, but in the C++ memory model, an operation is different from a 2-way fence.  (https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/)

Comment: I don't understand Fedor Pikus's comment in the video either.  It's unclear to me how a ticket lock could use an "acquire store"; I agree that the Wikipedia algorithm certainly doesn't need one.

Comment: Moreover, if Fedor wants to get the effect of an "acquire store" by doing an exchange (presumably acq_rel) and discarding the result, I think he's mistaken; as was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568185/for-purposes-of-ordering-is-atomic-read-modify-write-one-operation-or-two), an acq_rel RMW consists of an acquire load and a release store.  It does not prevent operations sequenced after the RMW from being reordered before the store (though they still cannot be reordered before the load).

Comment: If you really need to prevent something from being reordered before a store, AFAIK your only recourse is to use seq_cst on *both* the store and the other operation.  Nothing weaker suffices in the C++ memory model.