# C++ fetch_xx function memory order

Tags: c++, concurrency, memory-model

fetch_xx are RWM operations, but in the following code:

```
int item_index=count.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_acquire);
```

I know the load of fetch_sub is acquire, but which memory order is the store operation? is default memory_order_seq_cst?

compare_and_swap  and exchange are same question

Comment: If you are talking about [compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), its two memory order parameters are not for load and store, but for the success case (the comparison matched and the exchange happened; a RWM operation) and the failure case (the comparison failed, exchange didn't take place; a load operation). RWM is a single atomic operation, not two separate operations with separate orders.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes，thanks for reminding me, I have modified the question

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I actually think it *is* better to think of an atomic RMW as two operations with separate orders, but atomically linked so that no other operations on *this* variable can occur in between.  Operations on *other* variables can occur in between, even by the same thread, if otherwise allowed by ordering.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568185/for-purposes-of-ordering-is-atomic-read-modify-write-one-operation-or-two

Answer (score 1):

For the atomic read-modify-write instructions, `std::memory_order_acquire` means that the load is acquire and the store is *relaxed*.  Similarly, `std::memory_order_release` means that the load is relaxed and the store is release.

The idea is that you can do something like

```
// non-critical code
if (busy.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire) == 0) {
    // critical section
}
```

The load of 0 is what proves that this thread now owns the lock.  Thus the load needs to be acquire so that the critical section does not get reordered before the lock is taken.  But the store does not need to be ordered in any particular way with surrounding memory accesses.  It still remains atomic with the load, of course, but it would be okay if the non-critical code were reordered after the `fetch_add`.

This is stated in the standard only by omission; [atomics.order p1] says that `memory_order_acquire` performs an acquire operation, and does *not* say that it performs a release operation, whereas it says that `memory_order_acq_rel` does both.  And the sequentially consistent operations are only those for which `memory_order_seq_cst` is explicitly specified.  The atomic nature of the RMW is specified by p10 which promises that the read returns the value in the modification order immediately preceding the value that is to be stored.

There isn't any way to get a load that is acquire but not `seq_cst` together with  a sequentially consistent store.  I can't think of a case where you would want that, anyway.
If you need either half to be sequentially consistent then you have to upgrade the whole operation to `seq_cst`.

Note that in general when you have an atomic RMW, it is possible for other memory operations to be reordered *in between* the load and the store, if their memory orderings otherwise allow this.  See [For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568185/for-purposes-of-ordering-is-atomic-read-modify-write-one-operation-or-two)