# Is `seq_cst` strictly stronger or equally strong than `acq_rel`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

By *strictly stronger or equally strong*, I mean any `acq_rel` can be replaced by `seq_cst`, and this does not weaken any guarantees provided by `acq_rel` semantics.

When I read the cpp [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) literally:

> `memory_order_acq_rel`    A read-modify-write operation with this memory
> order is both an acquire operation and a release operation. No memory
> reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the
> load, nor after the store. All writes in other threads that release
> the same atomic variable are visible before the modification and the
> modification is visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic
> variable.
>
> `memory_order_seq_cst`    A load operation with this memory order performs
> an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and
> read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release
> operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads
> observe all modifications in the same order (see
> Sequentially-consistent ordering below).

I noticed `seq_cst` is missing a sentence that shows up in `acq_rel`:

> No memory reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the load, nor after the store.

And the reference further mentions (in a different section):

> in many cases, `memory_order_seq_cst` atomic operations are reorderable with respect to other atomic operations performed by the same thread.

These made me feel like `acq_rel` is a two-way barrier while `seq_cst` is no barrier at all. On the other hand, all texts that I have read say `seq_cst` provides stronger guarantee. I don't know if 1) `seq_cst` is also a barrier like `acq_rel`, and 2) if it's safe to "upgrade" any `acq_rel` into `seq_cst`.

Comment: It's strictly *at least* as strong.  Real implementations typically handle runtime-variable `memory_order` parameters by treating them as `seq_cst` instead of branching to maybe run fences or not.  ISO C++ doesn't *require* `acq_rel` to be weaker in any particular way, so we can't say that `seq_cst` is *strictly* stronger.  On real implementations it normally is. (Other than ARMv8.0 without `ldapr`, in that case there's no way to do an acquire load that doesn't wait for previous release operations to drain from the store buffer.  Hence ARMv8.something `ldapr`, partial-order wrt. `stlr`)

Comment: @PeterCordes *strictly* is my bad wording. What I really mean is *in every aspect*. By the way the [cpp draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order) has very little on `acq_rel`, and it doesn't mention the relationship of these two memory orderings.

Comment: Your Q is fundamentally ambiguous (one could even say ill formed), as *you don't say that you commit to only use RMW ops* (nobody does!) yet you use the notion of "memory_order_acq_rel" w/o committing to use the correct values (memory_order_acq OR rel) to simple load/stores. So the literal way of parsing your Q means "only RMW ops" and the realistic way of parsing your Q reads "load/store/RMW ops using resp. acq/rel/acq_rel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SC is acq_rel plus extra guarantees.  A few possibilities for the wording choices:

- `acq_rel` can be summarized more simply; `seq_cst` has extra guarantees about not reordering with other SC operations.
- Or the authors of the CppReference wiki documentation are avoiding repeating themselves with the assumption that the reader knows that `seq_cst` is no weaker than `acq_rel`.  That is indeed a true fact.

Remember it's not the normative standards wording; it tries to translate from standardese into something easier to think about.  (Such as memory ordering in terms of local reordering of accesses to coherent shared cache, which is a concept the ISO C++ standard doesn't include at all.  It only talks about happens-before guarantees or lack thereof.)

Fun fact: real implementations typically handle runtime-variable `memory_order` parameters by treating them as `seq_cst` instead of branching to maybe run fences or not.

> No memory reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the load, nor after the store.

This is already implied by the load being acquire and the store being release (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) which both paragraphs mention.

**Also, the guarantees are stronger for `seq_cst` so that wouldn't be as useful a summary**: earlier `seq_cst` stores also can't reorder with the load side of a `seq_cst` RMW, and later `seq_cst` loads can't reorder with the store side of a `seq_cst` RMW.  (I think that's true, that the individual parts of the RMW are at least as strong as a separate SC operations.)

Non-SC loads and stores on other sides of the SC RMW are still as limited by it as an `acq_rel` RMW.

---

> These made me feel like acq_rel is a two-way barrier while seq_cst is no barrier at all.

An `acq_rel` *operation* is not a two-way barrier for other operations on opposite sides of it.  The store side can reorder with later loads and maybe stores, as long as they're to different locations.

[For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568185/for-purposes-of-ordering-is-atomic-read-modify-write-one-operation-or-two)

`acq_rel` and `seq_cst` *fences* are two-way barriers (with `acq_rel` not blocking StoreLoad reordering).  `seq_cst` also does any other special stuff required to avoid IRIW reordering on ISAs where that's possible; `acq_rel` doesn't rule it out.  (*[Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see)*)

---

re: original phrasing of the question:

`seq_cst` isn't **strictly stronger** than `acq_rel`; ISO C++ doesn't *require* `acq_rel` to be weaker in any particular way.  A valid implementation could promote everything to `seq_cst` so they were exactly equal.

On real implementations, though, `seq_cst` normally is stronger for at least some operations.  (e.g. on x86, SC stores are done with `xchg` or `mov+mfence` to prevent StoreLoad reordering with later loads.  Everything else is the same between SC and acq_rel operations, although acq_rel fences are a no-op on x86 while SC fences are `mfence` or a dummy `lock`ed operation.)

ARMv8.0 without `ldapr` might promote acquire and `acq_rel` to `seq_cst`:  `ldar` loads wait for previous release operations to drain from the store buffer.  But ARMv8.3-A `ldapr` (partial-order wrt. `stlr`) is just `acquire` without that special interaction with release (and SC) stores from this core.

Comment: Do you know a minimal example of a program that is correct under `seq_cst`, but not under `acq_rel`?

Comment: @zch: There's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm .  Which just uses `seq_cst` loads and stores to achieve mutual exclusion without atomic RMWs (store-forwarding breaks it). But I guess that's not really `acq_rel`.  You could also invent litmus tests that fail under acq_rel but not seq_cst, for example by replacing the stores with RMWs in an IRIW litmus test ([Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27807118)), but that would just be a test case, not a useful algorithm.

Comment: @zch: You rarely actually need `seq_cst`; most real programs are fine with the cheaper `acq_rel` or just `acquire` or `release`

Comment: @PeterCordes how can *acq_rel* allow re-ordering stores with later loads? what if the operation does RMW using *acq_rel*? No following reads/writes can re-order with it for the load part of RMW. The opposite goes for the write side of RMW.

Comment: @minex: How can it?  Because not blocking StoreLoad reordering is one of the biggest differences between acquire / release vs. seq_cst.   https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ . 
 For RMWs, see [For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568185) for test on real hardware revealing this effect.  An atomic RMW doesn't have to keep its load/store glued together in the total order of all operations (if one even exists), it just has to make sure no other operations (including loads) *on that object* intervene.

Comment: @minex: The answer you're commenting under already linked both of those links and discussed the parts of an RMW reordering with other ops in the same thread unless they and the other ops are seq_cst.

Comment: @PeterCordes You said "An acq_rel operation is not a two-way barrier for other operations on opposite sides of it." Interesting. Should we conceptually see an acq_rel RMW as RW pair or WR pair? Your statement holds if it's RW but how do you know it's not WR? Is that from reference or from evidence?

Comment: @TSK: Other than `exchange`, the store value depends on the load value, so it's an acquire load and *then* a release store.  But if you modeled an exchange as a write then read, the read would see the value you just stored.  But an actual exchange reads the old value.  RW is right there in the name RMW.  I haven't checked the standard to see what the formalism surrounding this is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `seq_cst` is strictly stronger. (I.e. the standard imposes the same requirements on it as on acq/rel, and then some.)

> in many cases, `memory_order_seq_cst` atomic operations are reorderable with respect to other atomic operations performed by the same thread.

This isn't specific to `seq_cst`, all atomic operations can be reordered to some extent, but `seq_cst` additionally can't be reordered relative to each other.

I believe, the rules are:

- Operations on a single variable can never be reordered relative to each other, only relative to other variables.
- `seq_cst` operations can't be reordered relative to each other.
- Nothing can be reordered backwards across an acquire or seq-cst load, or forward across a release or seq-cst store.

> I noticed `seq_cst` is missing a sentence that shows up in `acq_rel`:
>
> > No memory reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the load, nor after the store.

Yes, looks like a bad wording to me. `seq_cst` has the same property.

The standard isn't worded in terms of reordering. It only says which atomic operations synchronize with each other. (If A synchronizes with B, all operations that happen before A will happen before all operations that happen after B.)

[`[atomics.order]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#1) says that both `release` and `seq_cst` writes are "release operations", and both `acquire` and `seq_cst` reads are "acquire operations".

Then [`[atomics.order]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#2) says that "release operations" synchronize with "acquire operations".

Comment: If you accept *No memory reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the load, nor after the store.* holds for seq_cst, then *memory_order_seq_cst atomic operations are reorderable with respect to other atomic operations performed by the same thread* cannot be true, because these two statements are conflicting each other?

Comment: @TSK I don't see a contradiction. Consider a seq-cst store, then a relaxed store a different variable. They can be reordered relative to each other, at least in theory. *"[can't] be reordered after the [seq-cst] store"* This doesn't apply, because we're reordering **before** the seq-cst store, not after (putting something that was initially after the seq-cst store, before the store; not the other way). Similarly, a relaxed load followed by a seq-cst load of a different variable can be reordered for the same reason.

Comment: Note that 1) none of the std thread semantics is formalized (attempted, failed, formalisation) in term of allowed reordering 2) not all allowed behaviors (under the subset of the formalisation that can be made to make any sense) can be explained in term of "reordering"

Comment: @curiousguy Which semantics are not formalized? Regarding reordering - I agree that the standard doesn't mention reordering, but what behavior can't be explained in terms of it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1) No part of the MT semantics in C/C++ has been standardized. No program in either C or C++ can be explained by the std. *We lost everything semantically. No program can be proven correct now!* 2) In term of allowed reordering, do you agree that a program where any thread only ever performs 1 operation on a shared object has 0 reordering issue by def? Is such program guaranteed seq-cst?

Comment: @curiousguy (1) What are you talking about? We have a lengthy description of the memory model since C++11. I have a feeling that you think there's some defect in the wording that makes every program undefined, or something of that sort. If so, can you tell us what it is? (2) You mean every object is accessed at most once per thread? The program is sequentally consistent only if every access is `seq_cst`. What counts as a "reordering issue"? If everything is `seq_cst`, there's no reordering, hence no issues; otherwise you could have some?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat (1) The defect is that no clause is even trying to define modern program execution. How do you even run a non threaded program? Sequentially? That's a new idea! (and old one actually, but a new one when threads are a thing, and threads aren't simply sequential executions). Why do you believe that C/C++ can get away w/ hard stuff with LESS efforts than an easier language like Java/JVM? (Easier in term of no UB.) What even prevents any C++ program from having UB from using a destructed mutex? What guarantees a mutex isn't destructed when you use it? Simply put, sequential exec!

Comment: So in my view, the sorry alternative is a) all programs have UB or b) *all atomic memory orders are bunk* (and try_lock failing is a reliable test, so a mutex lock is a release op too). Also, being unable to even approach the definition of "thin air" means you don't have a semantic. You just can't square that one. Any use of an atomic ptr would be UB, as nothing about prevent an invalid ptr value. The whole thing is an abject mess, as the designers simply dropped the ball and readers of the std, not knowing what a spec should look, like accepted it. Compare C++ and Java and it's obvious.

Comment: What I am saying here isn't a trivial remark like when I wrote that most use of a string literal is UB (as `cout << "Hello";` reads uninitialized memory). That one was an easy fix. The fix of C/C++ MT semantics implies redoing the whole thing (it's a rabbit hole and it legit frightens me). Starting with smthg like unavoidable outcomes, so `if(x) y=1; else z=2,y=1;` can do `y=1;` before reading `x`. I don't see anything in the std suggesting that. (It's hard because the low level CPU semantics is too close for elegance and confort.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat (2) "_The program is sequentally consistent only if every access is `seq_cst`_" (2a) Do you disagree w/ the stmt that a program correctly using mutexes is seq-cst? That any use of acq/rel atomics to implement mutual exclusion is seq-cst? (2b) What counts as a reordering issue: having multiple operations (read or modification) on shared variables, in succession in term of program order. Reordering applies to program order. A single op thread is one that only ever does one op on a shared var, say a thread doing only one `store` (silly but useful for illustration). So no reordering!

Comment: Conceptual asm reordering is when the compiler emits asm in opposite order (WRT program order) for two atomic ops. Of course in real world reordering is usually done by the CPU, but positing that the compiler reorders asm looks good to me for illustration issue.

Comment: @curiousguy *"What even prevents any C++ program from having UB from using a destructed mutex?"* Can you show a minimal program using a mutex that has this kind of UB, but is usually considered to be valid?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Any program that uses mutex in fact. You can't define a valid C++ program because you have no sequential jurisdiction. (It's like saying there is a law of the seas w/o knowing what sea even means.)

Comment: @curiousguy Do you have any links to articles decribing this, or is your personal research? I'm sorry, but this sounds like nonsense to me, unless you can provide more details, and clarify which exact parts of the standard are insufficient here, and in what ways. We have sequenced-before, synchronizes-with and the seq-cst order constraining the possible executions, any execution that doesn't contradict them is allowed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know how I can even try to explain it. There is no part defective in the std as there is no threads semantics at all in the std. We have a pure hoax. No part of the std even tries to define threads. We don't have any C/C++ semantics now, since threads were added. Pls contradict me showing one proof that one trivial thread program is correct. All the stuff you cite is a joke compared to the efforts the Java guys paid to make Java and JVM thread compatible. Remember we have to manage UB which Java doesn't have, and UB is not compatible w/ threads.

Comment: @curiousguy Can you elaborate what kind of wording exactly are we missing? All this is very vague. *"contradict me showing one proof that ..."* See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)

Comment: @curiousguy You're basically saying something like "all modern physics is broken since introduction of general relativity, it can't even properly describe (basic thing) at all, tell me how it describes (basic thing)". If you're making an extraordinary claim, it's on you to prove it, yet your're repeatedly refusing to.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nope. Nothing you wrote is even remotely applicable to what I write. Also physics isn't even related w/ semantics, we are discussing BOURBAKI not relativity. I did not make any claim initialy. I posted a Q and it got censored because ppl didn't like the fact they couldn't answer. Please provide ONE valid program in C++ and prove it valid. You can't because there is no semantic. It's all a HOAX that C/C++ has MT semantics.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Your physics analogy is actually pure genius but I failed to notice it at 1st, as I focused on judicial laws (prescription) vs. physical laws (description). You mention relativity (the general one), I would be more timid and stay with the special one. Indeed **the mere fact we discovered _c_ the speed of light destroyed everything**, exactly like adding threads destroyed everything! Knowing the constant _c_, we lost our understanding of "speed" and "distance" and "time" and had to rebuilt everything. Not just Newtonian laws (we still kept momentum invariance) but geometry itself!

Answer (score 0):

To put it very simply, making everything `seq_cst` meant as a **very cheap** alternative to making everything *strictly speaking `acq_rel`*, for which you would need to turn any pure load and pure store into a dismissing RMW operation (resp. dismissing the output or input), because:

- only a load can acquire
- only a store can release

Because without (at least conceptually) seeing a value set from a previous modification, **you can't even define what acquire even should mean**, and without adding a modification to the chain of modifications of an atomic object, you can't define what release means, because acquire and release only connect the history of objects and the state of the program (they don't "prevent re-orderings", as a program semantic is not a set of allowed "re-orderings").

(That of course does not mean that the modification must result in a different object state. The atomic object can have a modification into the previous state, it is still counted as a modification in the chain of modifications. It's just that other thread can't tell that a modification occurred from measuring the object state.)

Turning a memory write in assembly into an atomic RMW is already extremely costing, but turning a memory read into a write is madness, you would need to change the cache line to exclusive ownership for nothing. Reasonable implementations of atomic loads avoid doing that.